# I can't move WordPress site from one computer to another computer with XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I'm making new wordpress site and I have problems with moving it to another computer on XAMPP local host. For the last sites i used these steps [http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/][1] to upload it on live server and it worked but when I do the same on local machine I only get some broken html with mostof the css and I can't find where the problem is. Database name is the same as well as the 'localhost'. I exported the database in gzip and import it with the html and it didn't worked. Can you give directions where to look to resolve this situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see official docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Download your database as sql file. Open it in editor where you can find replace **Old URL** with **New URL**. And then upload it to new setup. Most of the times this solutions works perfectly.